# extract month, date, year using split

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract date, month and year from the below string.

```
my $test_str = "Jan 01, 2004    Feb 01, 2004    Mar 01, 2004    Apr 01, 2004    May 01, 2004";
foreach $s (split('\t', $test_str)) {
   my ($m, $d, $y) = split('[\s|,\s]');
   print ("$m=$d=$y\n");
}
```

when I print the output, $y is alway empty. Am I doing something wrong? the regx I have is

```
[\s|,\s] # match a space or space and a comma
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `split` regex `[\s|,\s]` is a character class (denoted by the `[]` brackets), which means: *"split on a single character that is either a whitespace, a pipe `|`, a comma, or a whitespace (again)"*. You will split the string `Jan 01, 2004` into four strings:

```
"Jan"
"01"
""        # comma + whitespace creates empty string
"2004"
```

You also split on the `$_` variable, but I assume that is a typo.

To fix your problem, change that line to:

```
my ($m, $d, $y) = split(/[\s,]+/, $s);
```

As you can see, the use of the `+` quantifier will strip multiple consecutive commas or whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this: `split /,?\s/, $s;`.

Answer (score 1):

Use strict and warnings and you'll find that `$s` causes compilation errors.

Then

```
my ($m, $d, $y) = split('\s|,\s', $s );
```

I just got rid of the `[]` brackets and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my $test_str = "Jan 01, 2004    Feb 01, 2004    Mar 01, 2004    Apr 01, 2004    May 01, 2004";
foreach my $s (split(/\t/, $test_str)) {
   my ($m, $d, $y) = split(/\s|,\s/,$s);
   print ("$m=$d=$y\n");
}
```

This gives the output that you want:

```
Jan=01=2004
Feb=01=2004
Mar=01=2004
Apr=01=2004
May=01=2004
```

As mentioned by the other folks who answered, `[\s|,\s]` is a character class matching exactly one of `\s`, `|`, or `,` (which is obviously not what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `split`, it is simpler in this case just to find all alphanumeric substrings in the target string. The `\w` pattern matches alphanumerics plus the underscore character, and is sufficiently accurate for this purpose.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test_str = "Jan 01, 2004\tFeb 01, 2004\tMar 01, 2004\tApr 01, 2004\tMay 01, 2004";

foreach (split /\t/, $test_str) {
   my ($m, $d, $y) = /\w+/g;
   print "$m=$d=$y\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Jan=01=2004
Feb=01=2004
Mar=01=2004
Apr=01=2004
May=01=2004
```